# Stored procedure for merging tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am doing some work at a client on their sales datamart, adding a new connection to their ERP. The client have kept the old database ('888') for manufacturing only and created a new '999' database for sales.  All history remains in 888 up until 31 December and new sales are in 999 from 1 Jan 2016 onwards.

I now have all the SQL Server tables and views set up to interrogate the ERP for both 888 and 999 using new tables and views as replicas of what we had previously for just 888. Now I want the union of the 888 and 999 data sets so we have a single data set.

I am pretty comfortable with creating the unions for the `fact` tables as there should be no duplicate records, however would like some guidance on the dim tables.

The customers and products were replicated out of 888 into 999 in the ERP so I absolutely *will* have duplicates, but I only want to have a single version from 999. However, say a customer gets deleted from 999, I still will have history from 888 so need to include it.

What I am thinking is that I can't actually do a union (because of the duplicates), rather I am thinking that I need to create some sort of procedure that inserts all the records from the 999 table and then processes the 888 against that, adding records where they do not exist in the target.

My problem is that I don't really know how I would write such a Stored Procedure. If I think of the `Customer` dimension as an example, the primary key is `[Order_Debtor]` and an example of a descriptive column is `[Order_Debtor_Description]`.

What I am looking for is guidance on writing the code that would do the insertion from `999.customer` into `merged.customer` and then the checking and insertion from `888.customer` into `merged.customer` when it does not exist in `merged.customer`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code as a proof you tried something yourself. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Comment: Hi #davejal, I don't have any idea how to do this, so have not tried to pull the code together.  I know what I need, but not how to do it!  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense, but we don't work for free and will not provide you a complete solution `out of our head`, try something and get back with what you tried and where you're getting stuck, then will help you for sure.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  If it's 2008 or above, there's lots of ways to skin this cat, including the MERGE statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: The client has SQL Server 2014.  Thanks Stuart.

Comment: Do you have duplicates in the 888 and 999 databases?  what is the datatype of the primary keys, and of any other unique identifiers.  Example do you have two versions of a customer ACME tools in 888?  perhaps say one ACME with an ID of 1234 and one ACME with an ID of 3456.  Do you care about the old system ID's or are you ok with creating new ID's if the situation arises?

Comment: Hi Brad, no, there are no duplicates within the databases, however please remember that 999 was created as a direct copy of 888. The unique identifier in each customer table is the Order_Debtor field. The IDs are identical between the two databases, so if Acme was 1234 in 888, it will be 1234 in 999. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you saying you originally loaded the datawarehouse from 888 by uploading all the data in, and now you want to change the source for your datawarehouse to be 999, and you want to ensure that you do not load duplicate records anywhere? If you are absolutely certain that ACME is the same debtor id in both systems (you should really check to be sure) then you can use a `INSERT INTO Target SELECT FROM Source WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Target WHERE Target.Debtor_ID = Source.Debtor_ID)`. Then it it will only records that don't have a matching debtor_id

Comment: But a full blown datawarehouse load is more sophisticated than this. Do you think this will be repeated (a copy of the ERP will be made?) Do you think you'll ever get a new source ERP to load? Does your datamart use surrogate keys?

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for responding in such a detailed manner. In answer to your questions: 1. This is a data mart which can be recreated in full from the source ERP systems. 2.The ERP source is both 888 & 999 databases. 3.The 999 database was created in the ERP as a replica of 888. 4.No I don't want to change the source from 888 to 999, rather I need to interrogate both, one to 31 Dec and the other from 1 Jan.... Con't

Comment: ... Con't... 5.As I am querying both 888 & 999 and there is duplicate dimension records ( eg Customer), I want to load the dim records for 999 and then supplement that with 888 records in case the dim member has been deleted from 999. Thanks Nick. John

Comment: Hi @BradD. Sorry, I just worked out how to use handles here.  Please see my responses above to replies. Thanks, John

Comment: Hi @StuartAinsworth, Sorry, I just worked out how to use handles here. Please see my responses above to replies. Thanks heaps, John

Comment: Can you clarify: is your datamart a bunch of views referring to the source databases or does it actually load a copy of data in? Normally you wouldn't need to 'interogate both', because both would be loaded into the datamart. When you refer to 'dimension' do you mean a standalone table in your datamart or do you mean a view pointing back at the source systems?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. The datamart loads data from the source.  I have, for example, tables called z888Customer and z999Customer. Both are identical and are loaded via SSIS jobs into the datamart. These tables are both dimension tables and are obviously separate from fact tables.  Cheers!

Comment: Normally you would have one customer dimension table that describes a customer in your business and can be loaded from any number of sources. A unique key in this table is a surrogate key (has no relation to anything except the fact). So your design is not what I had assumed. So anyway now that you have these two tables do you want to load non duplicates into a new table or do you want to put a view over them? If I understand correctly you simply want the unique combination of these tables which if I understand correctly is simply `UNION`

Comment: I suggest you add the definition of these tables, and also importantly indicate their unique keys to your question. The term 'datamart' introduces some assumpmtions as it's often used interchageably with 'ODS' and 'Data Warehouse'

Comment: Ok, thanks @Nick.McDermaid. I am sorry to have misled you somewhat.  Really, these z888Customer and z888Customer are stage tables that are going to be used to create the dim table.  In this dim table I need to eliminate duplicates, using the data from 999 first, then supplementing it with records from 888 where the unique key in both tables is the field [Order_Debtor]. There are other fields, such as [Order_Debtor_Description], but so long as I have the logic for a single non key field, then I can duplicate the logic for the others. Thanks again for your help and I'm sorry about the confusion!

Comment: It's OK you didn't mislead me it just helps to spell out what you're working with. I'm glad those are staging tables. Let me write up an answer but first tell me: are you using surrogate keys? This is for example an identity field which is the primary key of your dimension and a foreign key of your fact.

Comment: Hey @Nick.McDermaid, the only key is the single field , [Order_Debtor]. This key is then what the fact tables link to when the data is queried. I really appreciate your help on this.  Cheers, John

Comment: If you do a bit of reading on 'datawarehouse' and 'surrogate keys' you'll find this is not always a good idea. Surrogate keys for example allow you to totally switch source systems, or load from multiple systems, and allow for duplicate debtors or debtors changing over time. But it's another level of complexity. Just have a think about how likely it is that you will need to feed more systems into this datmart (i.e. if you have a seperate financial system that also has some of these same debtors but obviously with different keys, surrogate keys allow you to model this)

Comment: Yeah, I get what you are saying.  The likelihood of that being required is pretty low at this stage. If it did become a requirement, then I'd convince them to buy a real data warehousing tool, like Wherescape Red!

Answer (score 1):

Given tables `z888Customer` and `z999Customer` that have already been populated

As I understand it, here are the cases you've described for de-duplicating data:

```
Case    z888Customer        z999Customer         Use Data From
A       123                 (doesn't exist)      888
B       (doesn't exist)     789                  999
C       456                 456                  888
```

So one way to do this would be to create a view containing this:

```
-- Case A - only 888 records that are not in 999
SELECT Debtor_ID, Field1, Field2
FROM z888Customer
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM z999Customer
    WHERE z999Customer.Debtor_ID =  z888Customer.Debtor_ID
    )
UNION ALL
-- Case B and C
SELECT Debtor_ID, Field1, Field2
FROM z999Customer
```

Say that view is called LoadCustomers you can then only load new ones with:

```
INSERT INTO CustomerDimension (Field1,Field2,DebtorID)
SELECT Field1,Field2,DebtorID FROM LoadCustomers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM DimCustomer 
    WHERE DimCustomer.DebtorID = LoadCustomer.DebtorID
 )
```

So that will just keep adding stuff. Even if it gets deleted from the source, it wont get deleted from your dimension because there is no delete statement being run

We are using Debtor_ID as match key here. So you need to watch for these things:

- If DebtorID 63 gets deleted from a db but then gets recreated as a new completely debtor in that db reusing the same ID, it won't be reflected - the old one will stay the same
- If you have two different database I guarantee they will diverge. I suggest that you change the 'historical' database to be read only (`ALTER DATABASE SET READ_ONLY`, also set the files in the file system to read only) otherwise people will fiddle and you'll have problems
- I've only provided a `INSERT` case above. No update. This means if a debtor changes names in the source it won't be reflected in your data warehouse, because there is only an insert step not an update one

These are related to your 'replication' i.e. you are merging data in and you need to decide on rules for every case

Oh and one more thing consider using schemas to seperate your tables (not a z prefix)

so you dimension might be dbo.DimCustomer and your staging might be staging.888Customer. Often staging is a different database altogether though.

Comment: That's awesome @nick.mcdermaid !  Thank you very much.  I will try this out at my client next week and let you know how it goes.  Have a fantastic weekend.  John

Comment: You have a good weekend too. Just remember it comes back to your 'merge strategy' - what do you do for every case of data inconsistencies between two systems.